# Inversing DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, inverse

Input:

```
<content>
   <dom id=1>a</dom>
   <dom id=2>b</dom>
   <dom id=3>c</dom>
   <dom id=4>d</dom>
</content>
```

Output:

```
<content>
   <dom id=4>d</dom>
   <dom id=3>c</dom>
   <dom id=2>b</dom>
   <dom id=1>a</dom>
</content>
```

I'm looking for a function (if exists) like this:

$('content').inverse();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$(​$("content dom").get().reverse()).appendTo("content");​​​​​​​​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TSms6/), or if you like the reverse flavor:

```
$("content").append($("content dom").get().reverse());​
```

[Try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TSms6/1/).

Comment: You can compare the performance at http://jsperf.com/dom-node-reversal.  **Note:** Neither of the versions shown above works if there are multiple 'content' nodes on the page. The http://plugins.jquery.com/project/reverseorder plugin mentioned in the other answer works best, but is the slowest.

Comment: I like to use CORE functions of jQuery as well as possible, no plugins, this answer is what I want

Answer (score 2):

Use [**jQuery Reverse Order plugin**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/reverseorder)

jQuery Reverse Order uses jQuery to reverse the order of DOM elements on your page.

Example:

```
$('#items p').reverseOrder();
```

The plugin is quite simple:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.reverseOrder = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).prependTo( $(this).parent() );
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHnzm/)

Answer (score 0):

By using toArray() function in jQuery1.9, you can dump dom elements in to an array, and use reverse() function to accomplish your goal!

```
$('content dom').toArray().reverse()
```